# Linq get top 9 groups plus sum of all other groups as the 10th group

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

Is it possible in LINQ to do this:  Group by a field (LineTotal), returning only the top 9 groups and then in the 10th group return the sum of all other groups?

In SQL server this can be done like so:

```
with TopGroups as 
(
    select sum(sol.LineTotal) as ProductGroupSales, p.ProductGroupId,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY sum(sol.LineTotal) DESC) as Num
    from SalesOrderLines sol left join Products p on p.Id = sol.ProductId
    group by p.ProductGroupId
)
select ProductGroupSales from TopGroups where Num < 10
union all
select sum(ProductGroupSales) from TopGroups where Num >= 10
```

Can this be translated to LINQ?  I'm not sure how `ROW_NUMBER() OVER()` and `union all` translate to LINQ.

Comment: SQL statement above was inspired by the answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2601130/325727

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can translate the row number using "`.Take(9)`" and "`.Skip(0).Take(1)`".
2. `UNION ALL` maps to `seqA.Concat(seqB)`
3. A CTE maps to just a variable holding a query. Like so:

-

```
var q1 = SalesOrderLines.Where(...);
var q2 = q1.Concat(q1); //reused q1 multiple times for q2 like a CTE
```

All of these basically come at no performance cost on the SQL side.